# Javascript confirm validation form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to ask the confirmation to leave two fields in the form blank with javascript.. here there is the example 
**Teory**
Field1: Blank; Field2: Blank; Field3: Blank;
return false if the field1 in empy; ask confirmation for the other 2 such as "are you sure you want to leave the field #.. blank?" > if press ok, check the field3 otherwise return false
**code**

```
var field1 = document.form.field1.value;
var field2 = document.form.field2.value;
var field3 = document.form.field3.value;

if ((field1 == "") || (field1 == "undefined")) {
       alert("Cannot leave field1 blank");
       document.form.field1.focus();
       return false;
    }


     else if ((field2 == "") || (field2 == "undefined")) {      
     var x = confirm("Are U sure to leave field2 blank?");
  if (x)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
    }   


var y = confirm("Are U sure to leave field3 blank?");
  if (y)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
    }   

        else {
       document.form.submit();
    }
```

Of course it doesn't work... any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse you've to tell us what exactly is going wrong, "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. Apart from that, how have you defined `document.form`, it's not a native DOM property. Are you after [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) collection?

Comment: Can you include the HTML associated with this form?

Comment: <form name="form" method="post" AUTOCOMPLETE="Off"><input name="field1" type="text" ><input name="field2" type="text" ><input name="field3" type="text" ><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="Save()">

Comment: Your code has an odd number of braces.  The bottom section contains the extra close brace - what's going on here?

Comment: Doesn't work means that if both field2 and field3 are empty the form does NOT submit but I only have the confirmation message for the field2...

Comment: @raduation yeah because I cut some example from the entire form.. the brace is because of the function "Save"    function Save() {

Comment: Looks like you inadvertently left a closing curly brace, }, in the code just before your second confirmation, "Are U sure to leave field3 blank?"

Comment: Please post some complete, runnable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved thanks to a suggestion from yesterday (I can't see the message anymore?!)..
If someone need, the solution that works for me is below:

```
$ret = false
if ((field2 == "") || (field2 == "undefined")) {  
   var x = confirm("Are U sure to leave field2 blank?");
if (x) {
  $ret = true;
}
}   

if ((field3== "") || (field3== "undefined")) {      
if (confirm("Are U sure to leave field3 blank?")){
  $retu = true;
}   
}

if ( ($ret == true) && ($retu == true) ) {
document.form.submit();
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who help finding the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly rewritten your js. I hope it will help you out.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
var field1 = form.field1;
var field2 = form.field2;
var field3 = form.field3;

if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", formValidation);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", formValidation);
}

function formValidation(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    if ((field1.value == "") || (field1.value == "undefined")) {
        alert("Cannot leave field1 blank");
        field1.focus();
        return false;
    }


    else if ((field2.value == "") || (field2.value == "undefined")) {      
        var x = confirm("Are U sure to leave field2 blank?");
        if (!x) {
            field2.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }   

    else if ((field3.value == "") || (field3.value == "undefined")) {
        var y = confirm("Are U sure to leave field3 blank?");
        if (!y){
            field3.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    else {
        console.log("sending");
        form.submit();
    }
};
```

```html
<form action="" id="myform" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">
    <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have three different button on my form executing 3 different submit.. this is why I prefer using the button instead. I can post you the entire form later..